# Why is piping operator used here?

Tags: curl, pipe

Here are two commands I'm trying to understand. The first command downloads an installation script for `NVM` (nodejs version manager) and executes it. The second command installs `nodejs` using newly installed `nvm`.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
nvm install 14.15.1
```

My questions are:

1. What does `-o-` do? Couldn't find any info on it.
2. What is the point of using piping operator `|` here? Why not use a chaining operator `;`?

Answer (score 3):

A filename of "`-`", by convention, usually means "`STDOUT`", the standard output stream, so "`-o-`" writes `curl`'s output (the file it retrieved) to `curl`'s "`STDOUT`".

In this case, what's retrieved is a `bash` script, and the pipe ("`|`") connects `curl`'s output to `bash`'s standard input, to interpret (execute) the script.

This is a method for retrieving a script and executing it, without seeing what the script does. Not a good idea. It's a trust issue.

Comment: Sir, thank you! I now get it. Have a good day!!!

Comment: Please click on the Accept check mark, if my answer helped.